# How to add legends in map canvas when exported to PDF ol5

Tags: openlayers

Here is my code to export map in PDF and map is successfully exported to PDF
Now i want to add legends in map canvas but i do not know how to do that.

```
    var exportElement =  document.getElementById("export-pdf");
      exportElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            exportElement.disabled = true;
            document.body.style.cursor = 'progress';

      var format = document.getElementById('format').value;
      var resolution = document.getElementById('resolution').value;
      var buttonLabelElement = document.getElementById('button-label');
      var label = buttonLabelElement.innerText;
      var scale = 8000;

    var mapView = map.getView();
    var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
    var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
    var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
    var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection, mapResolutionAtEquator, viewCenter);

    var dim = dims[format];
    var width = Math.round(dim[0] * resolution / 25.4);
    var height = Math.round(dim[1] * resolution / 25.4);
    var size = map.getSize();
    var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(size);

    var mapView = map.getView();
    var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
    var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
    var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
    var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
    var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection, mapResolutionAtEquator, viewCenter);
    var mapResolutionFactor = mapResolutionAtEquator / mapPointResolution;
    var pdf_name = dist + "_" + tahsil + "_"+village+ ".pdf";
    map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) {

         buttonLabelElement.innerText = label;
          var canvas = event.context.canvas;
          var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
          var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
          pdf.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
          pdf.save(pdf_name);
          map.setSize(size);
          map.getView().fit(extent, size);
          map.renderSync();
          exportElement.disabled = false;
              document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }); 


    var printPointResolution = (scale * 25.4) /(resolution * 1000); 
    var printResolutionAtEquator = mapResolutionFactor * printPointResolution;
    var printZoom = mapView.getZoomForResolution(printResolutionAtEquator);        

    map.setSize([width, height]);
    mapView.setZoom(printZoom);
    map.renderSync();
   }, false);
```

see outout pdf looks too blur at 150 dpi or 300 dpi and even label is not clear.
[image]

Comment: If your legend is an image take a look at step 2 in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805963/how-to-export-openlayer3-map-to-png-with-its-scale-bar-using-js

Comment: my legends is not an image its just a color that shows boundary of district and village.

Comment: So it's a layer?

Comment: Question title mentions ol3. Code above uses `getZoomForResolution` method, so it's at least for ol4.

Comment: Yes TomazicM i edited the question for ol5.

Comment: I want to show color of layer as legends that show this color is for district and this color is for village so that that one can distinguish among color of layers in maps.

Comment: Can you supply a sample of such a legend?

Comment: yes TomazicM, i have uploaded sample pdf image..Pleas go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reasonable selection for legend seems to be `.svg` graphics. It is vector image, so it is scalable wihout loosing quality and easy editable with many free editors. This legend was created with Inkscape in 5 minutes:

[image]

The code to paint legend to canvas has to be outside `rendercomplete` event so that image has time to load. Parameter `placement` controls placement of legend on the map. By default legend is aligned top left on the map. If parameter contains letter `R`, legend is aligned right, if it contains letter `B`, it is aligned to the bottom.

```
var legendImage = new Image();
legendImage.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
legendImage.src = 'legend.svg';

function drawLegend(ctx, placement) {
  var canvasHeight = ctx.canvas.height;
  var canvasWidth = ctx.canvas.width;

  var legendHeight = canvasHeight * 0.10;  // legend height is 10% of map height
  var legendWidth = legendHeight * (legendImage.width / legendImage.height);
  var offset = canvasHeight * 0.01;

  var legendX;
  var legendY;

  placement = (placement === undefined) ? '' : placement.toUpperCase();
  if (placement.indexOf('R') >= 0)
    legendX = canvasWidth - legendWidth - offset;
  else {
    legendX = offset;
  };
  if (placement.indexOf('B') >= 0)
    legendY = canvasHeight - legendHeight - offset;
  else {
    legendY = offset;
  };
  
  ctx.drawImage(base_image, legendX, legendY, legendWidth, legendHeight);
}
```

Call to draw the legend can be just before `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')` statement. With the call below legend is aligned top left on the map:

```
...
drawLegend(event.context);
var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
...
```

Here is an example of semitransparent legend on 1:4000 map exported to PDF at 300 dpi:

[image]

There is one problem with this solution. I couldn't get this code to work in IE11. It has CORS problems because canvas source is coming from two different places. It works in Firefox and Chrome.

To make it work in IE11, bitmap image has to be used (`.png`, `.tif`, `.jpg`).

Comment: ok sir i will apply this then acknowledge you...thanks a lot.

Comment: may you plase tell me if i have to write something in top left of the canvas then what i have to do.

Comment: I modified the answer so that placement of legend on the map is controled with parameter.

Comment: Great  TomazicM sir. thanks for helping. you are such a genius.

Comment: now only one problem is there..when i am choosing 150dpi or 300dpi the pdf map is more dark & blur. I add image for this please go through it.

Comment: Regarding quality of the exported .pdf map: nothing more can be said than Ian Turton wrote in aswer to your question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315461/why-text-labeling-is-blur-when-export-to-pdf-ol5

Comment: Regarding writing some laable on top left of the canvas: this requires new question. You have to specify how this label should look like (border, background, font etc.)

Comment: Regarding your thanks: if answer helped you, you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: writing some label on top left is done. thanks.