# Why text labeling is blur when export to pdf ol5

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

Here is my code that displays wms image on map.

```
filter="VILL_NAME" + "=" + "'" +cad+ "'"+ " AND TEH_NAME" + "=" +"'" +tahsil+ "'"+ " AND DIST_NAME" + "=" +"'" +dist+ "'";
          cadLayer =new ol.layer.Image({
                    name: 'Cad layer',
              source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                   ratio: 1,
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
                params: {
                    'LAYERS': 'soil_health:RAIPUR_CAD_WITH_VILL_NAME_WGS84',
                    'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                    'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                    'TRANSPARENT': true,
                    'TILED': true,
                    'cql_filter':filter
                    },

                serverType: 'geoserver'                                            
              })});
              map.addLayer(cadLayer);
```

and here is my code to export map to pdf.

```
var dims = {
  a0: [1189, 841],
  a1: [841, 594],
  a2: [594, 420],
  a3: [420, 297],
  a4: [297, 210],
  a5: [210, 148]
  };

  var exportElement =  document.getElementById("export-pdf");
  exportElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        exportElement.disabled = true;
        document.body.style.cursor = 'progress';

  var format = document.getElementById('format').value;
  var resolution = document.getElementById('resolution').value;
  var buttonLabelElement = document.getElementById('button-label');
  var label = buttonLabelElement.innerText;
 var scale = 4000;

var mapView = map.getView();
var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection, mapResolutionAtEquator, viewCenter);

var dim = dims[format];
var width = Math.round(dim[0] * resolution / 25.4);
var height = Math.round(dim[1] * resolution / 25.4);
var size = map.getSize();
var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(size);

var mapView = map.getView();
var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection, mapResolutionAtEquator, viewCenter);
var mapResolutionFactor = mapResolutionAtEquator / mapPointResolution;
var pdf_name = dist + "_" + tahsil + "_"+village+ ".pdf";
map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) {

               // WriteLegendtoCanvas(event);
     buttonLabelElement.innerText = label;
      var canvas = event.context.canvas;
      /* event.context.textAlign = 'left';
        event.context.fillText('© My Copyright Text', canvas.width - 5, canvas.height - 5);*/
      var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
      pdf.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
      pdf.save(pdf_name);
      map.setSize(size);
      map.getView().fit(extent, size);
      map.renderSync();
      exportElement.disabled = false;
          document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
}); 


var printPointResolution = (scale * 25.4) /(resolution * 1000); 
var printResolutionAtEquator = mapResolutionFactor * printPointResolution;
var printZoom = mapView.getZoomForResolution(printResolutionAtEquator);        

map.setSize([width, height]);

mapView.setZoom(printZoom);
  map.renderSync();
}, false);
```

but when i open pdf my map is ok but text labeling is blur up to some extent. It is not clear up to the mark.

[image]

here i add sld or style for this layer in geoserver when i publish the map.Here is my sld code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 

 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- a Named Layer is the basic building block of an SLD document -->
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>default_polygon</Name>
    <UserStyle>
    <!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
      <Title>Default Polygon</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample style that draws a polygon</Abstract>
      <!-- FeatureTypeStyles describe how to render different features -->
      <!-- A FeatureTypeStyle for rendering polygons -->
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <Title>Gray Polygon with Black Outline</Title>
          <Abstract>A polygon with a gray fill and a 1 pixel black outline</Abstract>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill"></CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
       <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>

       <TextSymbolizer>
         <Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>KIDZ</ogc:PropertyName>
         </Label>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
       </TextSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Can anyone tell why text labelling is blur here.

Comment: At what resolution are you exporting to PDF?

Comment: A0,  70dpi as welll as  A0, 150dpi...but is is vrey slow.

Comment: how are you specifying the dpi to geoserver?

Comment: pragmatically  i am doing this A0, 70dpi as welll as A0, 150dpi..i am not specifying dpi for geoserver.

Comment: why not just request the map as a pdf? Then it would be a vector file and would scale to page size

Comment: how to  request the map as a pdf?

Answer (score 2):

To get GeoServer to produce images at any DPI other than the OGC standard of 90dpi you need to tell GeoServer what you would like. This is done using the [`format_options` parameter](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#format-options).

> dpi: sets the rendering DPI (dots-per-inch) for raster outputs. The OGC standard output resolution is 90 DPI. If you need to create high resolution images (e.g for printing) it is advisable to request a larger image size and specify a higher DPI. In general, the image size should be increased by a factor equal to targetDPI/90, with the target dpi set in the format options. For example, to print a 100x100 image at 300 DPI request a 333x333 image with the DPI value set to 300: &width=333&height=333&format_options=dpi:300

Comment: map is showing perfectly all right on web but when i export it to pdf then it is getting blur in pdf.

Comment: exactly - when you view it on web you are using 90dpi, in the printer it is probably more like 300dpi so 90 dpi text looks blury

Comment: still text labeling is blur in pdf. I just add format option as dpi:200 in WMS layer parameter.

Comment: did you increase the size of the image too?

Comment: size of image is adjusted like   a0: [1189, 841],
  a1: [841, 594],
  a2: [594, 420],
  a3: [420, 297],
  a4: [297, 210],
  a5: [210, 148]

Comment: did you see my code lan Turton sir?

Comment: the size of the image is specified in **pixels** not mm. You need to calculate size using DPI, mm/inch and paper size.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: width(px) = width(inch)*dpi(px/inch) = width(mm)*dpi(px/inch)*inch/mm